# Lost connection to device - Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

How to overcome lost connection when hot restart in VSCode? when want to reload Flutter code, please help me, thanks

[image: Lost Connection]

Comment: Maybe the problem is your package `shelf`. I think the logic of your code has some problem, maybe relate to initiate? Idk